# Z3 set default value of array to zero

Tags: z3

I am trying to solve models for array expressions, where default values for array is equal to 0.

For example, I am trying to solve this example, but I get unknown results all the time

```
(declare-const arr (Array Int Int))
(declare-const arr2 (Array Int Int))
(declare-const a Int)
(declare-const b Int)

(assert (forall ((x Int)) (= (select arr x) 0)))

(assert (> a 0))
(assert (<= a 10))

(assert (= arr2 (store arr a 1337)))

(assert (> b 0))
(assert (<= b 10))


(assert (= (select arr2 b) 0))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Patrick's advice on not using quantifiers is spot on! They'll make your life harder. However, you're in luck, because z3 supports constant-arrays for your use case, which is quite common. The syntax is:

```
(assert (= arr ((as const (Array Int Int)) 0)))
```

This makes sure `arr` will have all its entries as `0`; no quantification needed and z3 handles it internally just fine.

So, your benchmark will be:

```
(declare-const arr (Array Int Int))
(declare-const arr2 (Array Int Int))
(declare-const a Int)
(declare-const b Int)

(assert (= arr ((as const (Array Int Int)) 0)))

(assert (> a 0))
(assert (<= a 10))

(assert (= arr2 (store arr a 1337)))

(assert (> b 0))
(assert (<= b 10))


(assert (= (select arr2 b) 0))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

which is solved in no time. This way, you can have the entire array start with `0`, and modify the range you're interested in; which can depend on variables as usual and is not required to be known ahead of time.

Comment: I like this solution, it brings together the best features of the two worlds.

Comment: I don't think this feature is part of the SMTLib standard. but I do know that z3, cvc4, and mathsat all support it. So, it's practically the standard!

Comment: The [documentation](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories-ArraysEx.shtml) seems to be particularly lacking on this regard, when compared to BV/FP, unless I am looking at the wrong page.

Comment: I've found one reference in section 3.6.4 of http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2017-07-18.pdf, but it's only in an example. (And also uses the term `const-array`, which isn't the syntax supported by Z3 at least.) It'd be nice to send a note to the SMTLib mailing list and ask about it.

Comment: I saw the same thing but as you say it doesn't match your example quite well :)